# Extract string from a column to make a new column

Tags: sql

I have a column that has a code I need to parse out. I can use substring and charindex to grab what I want, but how can I make it into a column of its own? To show what I mean, I have a column with the following and my code to take the two characters after the asterisk is

```
SUBSTRING([table].Service_Description, CHARINDEX('*', [table].Service_Description)+1,2). 
Example data:
CES - Community Connector *GG (H2021)
CES - Respite *QG (S5150)
CES - Respite Day *RG (S5151)
```

I have searched and searched but no answers fit my specific situation.

```
select [table].Service_Description, SUBSTRING([table].Service_Description, CHARINDEX('*', [table].Service_Description)+1,2) from [table]
```

Comment: Well, you already got a new column in your result set. If you want to store it as a new column in your table you must add the column first and then Update. Or you use a Calculated Column (some DBMSes support that) or you simply create a view.

Comment: What do you mean by "a column of its own"? Isn't the expression already creating its own column in the result of the query? And is this for SQL Server? Or for which other DBMS? Please update the tags of the question to show the used DBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add such a column as a computed column:

```
alter table [table] add new_column as
    (SUBSTRING([table].Service_Description, CHARINDEX('*', [table].Service_Description)+1, 2));
```